# Dynamically updating a WPF Window before code finishes executing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is probably a really basic question, please bear with me, I'm still very new to the world of WPF/C#.

I have a WPF app where I open a new window if a button is clicked.

The window is called Sync and all it does is instantiate a viewmodel class which contains some public properties that are bound to my view.

The viewmodel also instantiates a class containing a lot of business logic, this updates the ViewModel's bound properties, the aim being to update the content of my window.

This sort of works, but only when all of the (sometimes quite lengthy) processing is completed does the window load and the view is populated with the last value of the ViewModel's properties.

I think I'm missing something pretty basic here. How do I get my window to instantly load and then have the view update when any of the properties have changed? Should I be listening for a PropertyChanged event and then updating the view? Where do i do this? Within the view model's setter?

Here's some simplified code:

Calling my window from my main window's View Model

```
public void SyncAction()
    {
        Sync syncWindow = new Sync();
        syncWindow.Show();
        syncWindow.Activate();
    }
```

The window

```
public partial class Sync : Window
{
    public Sync()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new SyncViewModel();
    }
}
```

The view model

```
class SyncViewModel
{

    private string _miscStatus = "";

    public SyncViewModel()
    {
        var sync = new SyncLogic();
        sync.SyncAll(this);
    }

    public string MiscStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _miscStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _miscStatus += value;
        }
    }
}
```

Some business logic

```
class SyncLogic
{
    private ViewModel.SyncViewModel _syncViewModel;

    public void SyncAll(ViewModel.SyncViewModel syncViewModel)
    {
        _syncViewModel = syncViewModel;

        // lock our synctime
        var syncTime = DateTools.getNow();

        _syncViewModel.MiscStatus = "Sync starting at " + syncTime.ToString();

        // Do lots of other stuff

        _syncViewModel.MiscStatus = String.Format("Sync finished at at {0}, total time taken {1}", 
            DateTools.getNow().ToString(), (DateTools.getNow() - syncTime).ToString());
    }
}
```

Bonus question: The way I'm updating the view from within my business logic (by passing in a reference to the viewmodel and updating its properties from there) seems a bit kludgy. I definitely want to keep the business logic separate, but am not sure how I can pass any output back out to the viewmodel. What would be a better way of doing this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

Don't do any heavy logic in the ViewModel constructor. Constructor should only initialize object and do nothing else. In your example, constructor should be empty.

```
public SyncViewModel()
{       
}
```

`SyncLogic` should not be aware of the ViewModel. Introduce some other class to communicate input arguments and sync results. Let's say `SyncArguments` and `SyncResult`.

```
class SyncLogic
{
   public SyncResult SyncAll(SyncArguments syncArgs)
   {
      var syncResult = new SyncResult();

      // Do lots of other stuff
      // populate syncResult
      return syncResult;
  }  
}
```

Introduce a method in the viewmodel that should be called to do the "sync" logic, and make that method `async`. That way it's very easy to do the heavy stuff in the background and leave the UI thread to do the job it should do, draw the UI.

```
public async Task Sync()
{
    // lock our synctime
    var syncTime = DateTools.getNow();
    MiscStatus = "Sync starting at " + syncTime.ToString();


    var sync = new SyncLogic();
    var syncArgs = new SyncArguments();
    //populate syncArgs from ViewModel data

    //call the SyncAll as new Task so it will be executed as background operation
    //and "await" the result
    var syncResults = await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>sync.SyncAll(syncArgs));

    //when the Task completes your execution will continue here and you can populate the   
    //ViewModel with results

     MiscStatus = String.Format("Sync finished at at {0}, total time taken {1}", 
        DateTools.getNow().ToString(), (DateTools.getNow() - syncTime).ToString());

}
```

Make the button click event handler that creates and shows the window `async`, so you can call `Sync` method on the ViewModel

```
private void async Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sync syncWindow = new Sync(); 
    var viewModel = new SyncViewModel();
    syncWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
    syncWindow.Show();
    syncWindow.Activate();
    await viewModel.Sync();
}
```

That will draw the Window without waiting on the Sync method. When the Sync taks completes, viewmodel properties will be populated from the SyncResult and the Bindings will draw them on screen.

Hope you get the idea, sorry if there are some errors in my code, not sure that it all compiles.

Comment: All of the answers to my question were very helpful and allowed me to increase my understanding, however this one gave me the biggest head start and I've now successfully implemented something similar that a) works as I'd intended and b) is much more maintainable. Thanks @jure

Answer (score 2):

Why do you *care* whether the update takes visual effect before or after the code finishes executing?  The internal properties are updated immediately; any code that queries the UI will see the new values.

The only time the user will be able to perceive a difference between an update *during* execution vs *after* execution is if you have a long-running computation on the UI thread.  Don't do that.

Instead, run the computation asynchronously with the UI, so that repaint messages can be processed meanwhile.  You can do this using a background thread, but the new easier way with C# 4 and later is `async`.  Because `async` is implemented using continuation messages to the UI thread, you don't need to synchronize data access or marshal UI access between threads.  It just works, and very well.  The only thing you need to do is to break your code into small enough chunks, each implemented as an `async` method, that you don't cause noticeable delay.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to set the viewmodel as the view's DataContext:

```
public partial class Sync : Window
{
    public Sync()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new SyncViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Second, you'll have to run the "sync" stuff on a background thread.  This is easiest with the async+await keywords in .Net 4.5:

```
public async void SyncAll(ViewModel.SyncViewModel syncViewModel)
{
    _syncViewModel = syncViewModel;

    // lock our synctime
    var syncTime = DateTools.getNow();

    _syncViewModel.MiscStatus = "Sync starting at " + syncTime.ToString();

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        // Do lots of other stuff
    });

    _syncViewModel.MiscStatus = String.Format("Sync finished at at {0}, total time taken {1}", 
        DateTools.getNow().ToString(), (DateTools.getNow() - syncTime).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With databinding your Window will automatically updated as long as it notified that properties it bound to has been changed. So what you need is implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the viewmodel and raise property changed event whenever binding source property value changed. For example:

```
public class SyncViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _miscStatus = "";
    public string MiscStatus
    {
        get{ return _miscStatus; }
        set
        {
            _miscStatus += value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MiscStatus");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very succinct explanation on how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, very helpful, I was very nearly there, but wasn't sure how to trigger the changed property. I now need to implement the 'async' related suggestions to get my window immediately opening.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else comes across this issue in WPF, the solution described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx) is really simple and just worked fine for me. It uses an extension method to force an UIElement to be rendered:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

   private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };


   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }
}
```

Then, simply use as:

```
    private void SomeLongOperation()
{
   // long operations...

   // UI update
      label1.Content = someValue;
      label1.Refresh();

   // continue long operations   
   }
}
```

Quoting the original author:

> The Refresh method is the extension method that takes any UI element and then calls that UIElement's Dispatcher's Invoke method.  **The trick is to call the Invoke method with DispatcherPriority of Render or lower**.  Since we don't want to do anything, I created an empty delegate.  So how come this achieves refresh functionality?
>
> When the DispatcherPriority is set to Render (or lower), **the code will then execute all operations that are of that priority or higher**.  In the example, the code already sets label1.Content to something else, which will result in a render operation.  **So by calling Dispatcher.Invoke, the code essentially asks the system to execute all operations that are Render or higher priority, thus the control will then render itself** (drawing the new content).  Afterwards, it will then execute the provided delegate (which is our empty method).